# C# print labels in Zebra - Server side/Client Side

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-server-2008, intranet, zebra-printers

I have a intranet application that print labels with Zebra tlp 2844 with the EPL language. I used the [SharpZebra](http://sharpzebra.codeplex.com/) to do this codes. 
When i debug my code with the printer connected in lpt1 of my machine, everything works normally...But I need to publish my code in the server (Windows server 2008) and Print with another machine with contains another printer connected. How i do this ?
I tried to share the printer and add in the server, but not work...When i try to print, it seems that the printer is not found...I need to do more some thing ?

I googled it, and not found a good answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bought a print server and this resolve my question. I connected the printer in Print Server and the Server of the system recognized this printer.

Answer (score 1):

I usually save the EPL or ZPL to a file and then just do a 'copyfile' to the UNC path of the printer. If SharpZebra lets you save it as a file you might try that. It works nicely to just copy the raw file to the printer. (I havent used SharpZebra).

Comment: Interesting...you have an example that show how save and copy file to the UNC path of the printer ? I think SharpZebra only send commands directly for the Zebra prints. But when the Zebra isn't connected in the server, it isn't recognized.

Comment: I havent used the SharpZebra so I'm not sure it has the ability to save to a raw EPL or ZPL file (but that is what it is sending to the printer I'm sure). The program I use saves the file as text and then we just do FSO.CopyFile labelpath,printerUNCpath  (this is using filesystem object).

Answer (score 0):

If you can save the receipt design as raw ZPL text, you should be able to open the file and send it to the printer via a telnet connection. That would let you print to any networked zebra printer without the need for driver installation on the server.

Answer (score 0):

With communication between sockets. You send the barcode string to client in the socket. IN the client side, make a socket. This listen in un port, and receive the data, and put this in the serial port.